# java missing class when supervisor running process but not when running as www-data user

Tags: java, jdbc, clojure, leiningen, supervisord

I've made my first clojure app and I've built it with leiningen by running `lein ring uberjar`. I can run this on my dev machine (fedora 23) and I can run this on my ubuntu production machine `java -jar tomahawk.jar`. I've followed the digital ocean tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-clojure-web-application-on-ubuntu-14-04) that describes how to set up the environment. My supervisor conf is the following:

```
[program:tomahawk]
environment=TOMAHAWK_DB=$TOMAHAWK_DB
command=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar tomahawk.jar
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log
directory=/var/www/tomahawk/app
user=www-data
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/logs/tomahawk.app.log
```

However, when using this through nginx, i get the error

```
2016-03-19 23:34:08.594:WARN:oejs.AbstractHttpConnection:/
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:$
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$get_connection.invoke(jdbc.clj:255)
```

This comes from the com.microsoft.sqldbc4.jar file. However, I can run this standalone jar file, as well as I can run `sudo -u www-data env TOMAHAWK_DB=$TOMAHAWK_DB java -jar tomahawk.jar` just fine. Also, while this is running, I can hit it through the nginx reverse proxy.

I've searched around and found an unanswered email on the supervisor mailing list from 2011. Why can I only sometimes see the missing jar file?

I've tried putting it inside of the /usr/lib/jvm/.../lib/ext location for my jvm, bundled inside of the jar file, running from Tomcat, etc. I've made an upstart script as well with identical results as well. I am not sure what other paths I can try and was wondering if anyone had any insights.

Comment: Do your drivers depend on native code?

Comment: What does `java -version` return when you run from the commandline (both as the supervisor and www-data)? BTW: Don't put stuff in `/lib/ext`, it is deprecated and will be removed in future Java versions. Also check if www-data as read rights on all files (and execute right on all folders) that contain your application and dependencies.

Comment: Bill, I'm not sure if the drivers depend on native code. The one in question is a jdbc4 4.0 driver from microsoft and it says it can run on just about all OS's.

Comment: java version is always 1.7. I've made sure www-data has read rights to everything, and it sucessfully runs when i invoke the command as the user www-data, as well as when i run it with my user account. It is just when i automate the command that it seems to not be able to see its dependency

Comment: How do you pass DB URL? From the exception message it looks like your URL is just `$`. Is it correct? Are you using environment variables for passing config values?

Comment: Piotrek. I set an /etc/environment variable and then set it in the environment for the supervisord process according to their docs. When that variable is not passed in there is a separate error that is thrown in the execution path before this one. I have seen it before and have mitigated it. This is further along when trying to execute the query against my db. The URL is not just $; $ expands the following environmental variable.

Comment: The fact the error shows `No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:$` means that no expansion took place (or incorrectly) and that was the actual JDBC url offered to the driver. I thought it was just some form of anonymization.

Comment: oh this is perfect! I changed the supervisor conf file to have a hardcoded string and it all worked. Thank you so very much. I'm pretty new to actually interacting on stack overflow so I'm not sure how to mark this as the answer but please accept some heartfelt gratitude.